# How to set align of view without xml in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, position

I don't use xml in my UI.

My code of mainlayout:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

LinearLayout LinLay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    this.setContentView(sv);

    LinLay = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinLay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    sv.addView(LinLay);
```

And adding a Edittext:

```
EditText txt = new EditText(this);
    txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff9a16"));
    txt.setHint("Txt(0,0)");

    LayoutParams txtParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    txtParams.width = 300;
    txtParams.height = 70;
    txtParams.leftMargin = 0;
    txtParams.topMargin = 0;

    txt.setLayoutParams(txtParams);

    LinLay.addView(txt);
```

Finally adding a Button:

```
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cb0016"));
    btn.setText("Btn(0,0)");

    LayoutParams btnParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnParams.width = 300;
    btnParams.height = 70;
    btnParams.leftMargin = 0;
    btnParams.topMargin = 0;

    btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);

    LinLay.addView(btn); }
```

The Edittext's must be X position = 0 and Y position = 0 of MainScreen.
The Button's must be X position = 0 and Y position = 0 of MainScreen.
But the Button taking referance is the Edittext and it takes position in X:0,Y:70 of MainScreen.

The program screen: prntscr.com/4ixo7z

If my LinearLayout that's LinLay is Horizontal, the button takes position in X:300,Y:0 of MyScreen. I want to taking position in MainScreen. I don't want to taking referance. Help me.

The Horizontal screen: prntscr.com/4ixo8i

Comment: Do you mean position of text inside the Button?

Comment: No :) There are two widget, they are orange Edittext and red Button. I want to position them by MainScreen.

Comment: Strange thing is, I run your code, and get them on 0,0 only. Can you share screenshot of what you get and what you want?

Comment: I want to : http://prntscr.com/4iyacf

Comment: Is this what you want? or what you get?

Comment: Yes, What I want to say in the picture.

Comment: Then change margins to `txtParams.leftMargin = 75;
    txtParams.topMargin = 90;` and `btnParams.leftMargin = 100;
    btnParams.topMargin = 230;`

Comment: I'm doing you are say but it there is e error in the btnParams.topMargin. I'm doing btnParams.topMargin = 230; but the button get reference the edittext. What I mean is in the screen: http://prntscr.com/4iylhe

Answer (score 0):

Change your LinearLayout and use RelativeLayout, remove orientation. add your product relatively, this will solve your issue.

Comment: I apply your suggestion but don't work. When it is RelativeLayout, the EditText and the Button are X:0,Y:0 in MainScreen but leftmargin and topmargin don't work. The button is over the EditText and I don't position them.
The Screen: http://prntscr.com/4ixze1

Comment: Check for RelativeLayout params and pass them when you add your edit text or button to layout.

Comment: How to pass? Don't understand.